# Работа vuex и vue-router при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue-router

Что происходит с vue-router и vuex при перезагрузке страницы? По какой-то неведомой мне причине, при перезагрузке некоторых страниц происходит что-то странное. 
Перешли на компонент по ссылке с главной страницы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Теперь перезагружаем страницу:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаем огромное количество ошибок.

Как я понимаю, при перезагрузке сбрасывается состояние хранилища. Но тогда почему не для всего state и почему оно не обновляется?

В общем, итоговый вопрос звучит так: в какой хук подгружать данные, в какой скрипты. Интересен порядок этого.

Comment: Кстати, разобрался с обновлением хранилища. Но ошибки остались, поэтому я думаю проблема в хуках все таки.

Answer (score 0):

В консоли прописано что переменная id undefined, ищите ее в коде и смотрите было ли ей присвоено какое-то значение

Comment: Я разобрался в чем здесь дело. Данные не успевают загружаться до того, как компонент смонтирован, и поэтому при выводе данных возникают такие проблемы. Я вот думаю может какой-то колбэк вызвать при загрузке всех данных?

Comment: Если данные не успевают загружаться, то попробуйте поменять порядок выполнения скриптов в html документе, напомню, что они выполняются последовательно. К скрипту где идет загрузка данных добавьте



    <script src="..." defer>




Аттрибут "defer", говорит странице: "Не продолжать загрузку страницы, пока не загрузится текущий скрипт"

Comment: спасибо за совет. Вы меня немного не так поняли, потому что я плохо объяснил. Я имел ввиду данные с сервера. Там осуществляется асинхронный запрос на сервер и данные отправляются в хранилище vuex. Сейчас я выяснил, что нужно использовать Promise.